# How to get menu overflow in Primefaces Extension with fullpage layout?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, overflow, primefaces-extensions

The problem is that my menu goes always under the center pane and I have no idea how to fix this. I have tried to change css, but when changing pe-layout-pane-content overflow values, scrollbar is not visible any more and without it z-index in pe-north is not helping at all. This is driving me crazy because it used to work when using p:layout with css-changes.

I have just template like that:

```
<h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="global.css"/>
        <style type="text/css">


            .noBorders tr, .noBorders td {
                background: none !important;
                border: none !important;
            } 
        </style>
 </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <pe:layout  fullPage="true" > 

            <pe:layoutPane  position="north" size="50"  resizable="false" closable="false" spacing="0" rendered="true" >  
                <ui:insert name="north">

                    <ui:include src="/resources/templates/menuBar.xhtml"/>    
                </ui:insert>
            </pe:layoutPane>  



            <pe:layoutPane position="west" size="215"  resizable="true" closable="true" spacing="-3">  
                <ui:insert name="west">

                </ui:insert>         
            </pe:layoutPane>   



            <pe:layoutPane position="east" size="200"  resizable="true" closable="true" spacing="-4" >  
                <ui:insert name="east"> 

                    <ui:include src="/resources/templates/commonRight.xhtml"/>  
                </ui:insert>
            </pe:layoutPane> 




            <pe:layoutPane position="center"  size="800" resizable="false">  
                <h2>
                    <ui:insert name="title">Default Title</ui:insert>
                </h2>

                <ui:insert name="center">

                    Center from newTemplate

                </ui:insert>
            </pe:layoutPane> 

            <pe:layoutPane position="south" rendered="false" statusbar="false" size="60"  resizable="true" closable="true" spacing="0">  
                <ui:insert name="south">


                    <ui:include src="/resources/templates/commonFooter.xhtml"/>


                </ui:insert>
            </pe:layoutPane>  

        </pe:layout>  
    </h:body>
```

And then my menuBar.xhtml is like that:

```
<h:head>
        <title>menuBar.xhtml</title>



    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition>
            <h:form>
                <p:menubar rendered="true" style="border: none; z-index: 9998; overflow: visible" >
<p:submenu label="#{bundle.menuBar_partners}" icon="ui-icon-document">
                        <p:menuitem value="#{bundle.menuBar_partners_info}" url="#"/>
                        <p:submenu label="cars" icon="ui-icon-contact" >
                            <p:menuitem value="www.rangerover.com" url="http://www.rangerover.com"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="www.lada.com" url="www.lada.com"/>
                        </p:submenu>
</p:submenu>


                </p:menubar>


            </h:form>
        </ui:composition>

    </h:body>
```

I would be very very thankful if somebody knows how to fix this.
Sami

Answer (score 4):

When I use this CSS with regular primefaces layout and layoutUnit, overflow works fine for my north menu, but when I use the same CSS with pe layout and layoutPane, it does not.

```
.ui-layout-north {
    z-index:40 !important;
    overflow:visible !important;
}
.ui-layout-north .ui-layout-unit-content {
    overflow:visible !important;
}
```

Perhaps you can switch to p layout and layoutUnit for now as primefaces extensions seems to have broken the overflow with CSS.

Also, with pe, I get a stupid scrollbar on the right of my north menu but with p I don't.

And, it might be nice if Oleg gives us a CSS solution if there is one and keeps us posted when his update fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

you should make the following change to your css

```
.ui-layout-north {
     z-index:40 !important;
     overflow:overflow !important;
}

.ui-layout-north .ui-layout-unit-content {
    overflow:overflow !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sami, we have disussed this in the PF Extensions forum http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=22621&start=20 You have now scrollbars. Regarding menus, try to play with higher z-index on menu.

I plan to re-implement the layout component in the next release to fix some known issues, enhanche the layout with more features and allow an AJAX update on nested child layouts.

Thansk. Oleg.